# what is the max number of operations per 1 transaction?

Tags: stellar-sdk, stellar-laboratory

what is the max number of operations per 1 transaction?

I cannot find the document related to this number from the official document.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Transactions contain an arbitrary list of operations inside them. Typically there is just one operation, but it’s possible to have multiple (up to 100).

This is the documentation I believe you're looking for: https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/transactions.html#list-of-operations